# How to add 2 decimal numbers

Tags: javascript

When the user enters 1.1 + 1.1 the decimals are ignored and the returned input is rounded up to 2. How can I add two decimal numbers together? I tried changing my parseInt to another method in Number() but I get the same results

`function add(a,b){ return display.innerHTML = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b) }`

Comment: You're looking for `parseFloat`

Answer (score 2):

`parseInt(x)` rounds the number as an Integer must be a whole number, use `parseFloat(x)` to correct this.

```js
function add(a, b) {
  return parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b)
}

console.log(add(2.43, 5.4545));
```

Also addition on two float number will result in a float.

```js
const a = 2.344;
const b = 34.444;
console.log(a + b);

console.log((a + b).toFixed(2));
console.log((a + b).toFixed(4));
```

You might also want to look at [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) which formats the result toa given number of decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

As Evert said, you are looking for `parseFloat()`. You said you tried changing `parseInt()` to another method in Number, which did you change it to?

`parseInt()` will always return an integer, which will never have anything after the decimal.

`parseFloat()` will return a float which is able to have stuff after the decimal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Number` function, `parseFloat`, or the unary plus operator.

```js
display.textContent = +a + +b;
// or
display.textContent = Number(a) + Number(b);
```